# Extracting and saving the charts of excel in a directory using java/python

Tags: java, python, excel

Is there a way to extract the image/chart that is generated in the excel as per any values (static or dynamic)

For example , if we look into the below given case,The bar chart generated is because of the values mentioned and if I want to extract it through java/python I am unaware that how could I accomplish it, as this chart is not present in any particular cell and hence even after opening the sheet at which it is present there is no way to access it.

[image]

Is there a way to copy this and paste to any directory?

Comment: Won't the chart be in some arbitrary microsoft format? You're okay with that?

Comment: I am not aware how that format will behave once the chart is extracted but for initial stage I can ignore the format , just extracting the chart is main objective, I will check about the format in later stage.

Comment: Do you want to extract the chart as an image or do you need the data?

Comment: I need chart as an image.